# Updating of a config file written in python

Tags: python, parsing, config

I'm writing a simulation software which should support reading parameters from a config file or from the command line. It is very important to be able to track what was the configuration of a simulation, I'm committing the config file to a local git repository at the start of simulation.

Now if I have parameters on the command line they have higher priority than the ones in the config file. But I also want to commit them. I guess I could save the python objects of a configured simulation, just before it is started. But it would be more elegant, if I could just update the config file with the command line parameters before committing it.

The reason I write the config file in python is that I have to define some python objects in it. I have something like

```
import SomeSimulationClass
SIMULATOR = SomeSimulationClass
```

in my config file and the SIMULATOR can then be swapped easily.
If I want to use something like configparser I can't have objects I believe.

Is there any easy way to update a python config file? All variable names in it are already defined, I just want to change the values. The only thing I can think of is parsing the file, comparing strings between the file and the command line parameters ...

Comment: do you know `configparser` module? use that.

Comment: In a similar situation I defined all my variables/objects fields in a configuration file (ini format). Then I wrote a function to initialise all the objects and variables depending on the configuration file read, giving default values when needed. Require some thoughts about the organisation of the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write whatever you want into a file, and then later, Configparser can read 
from it using values from your variables. Here is an example on how I used Configparser to read environment from config file.

```
import os
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

conf_filename = os.getenv("CONFIG_FILE")
src_dir  = os.getenv("CONFIG_DIR")
conf_file = os.path.join(src_dir,conf_filename)
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read(conf_file)
section = env
server = parser.get(section, 'host')
db_port = parser.get(section, 'db_port')
ws_port = parser.get(section, 'ws_port')
```

and the config file itself:

```
[PROD]
host=xxx-yyy-15
db_port=1521
ws_port=8280
ora_server=xxx-xxx-xxx.com
sid=XXXXX
userid=xxxx
passwd=xxxx
[STAGE]
host=xxx-yyy-04
db_port=1521
ws_port=8280
ora_server=yyy-yyy-yyy.com
sid=YYYYYY
userid=yyyy
passwd=yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I want. Some small modifications were necessary to my python config module to allow it to be rewritten with the following script, but it works for my purposes:

```
    with open('merged_config.py', 'w') as merged_config, \
            open(base_config_module.__file__, 'r') as base_config:
        for line in base_config:
            if 'import' in line:
                # copy imports from bas config
                merged_config.write(line)

        for item in dir(base_config_module):
            if item.startswith("__"):
                # ignore __variables like '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__' ...
                continue
            if item == 'SimulationSteps':
                # ingoring my imports
                continue

            item_val = getattr(base_config_module, item)
            # I had to overwrite the __repr__() method of Enums which I used. Everyting else worked fine.
            merged_config.write('%s = %s\n' % (item, repr(item_val)))
```